# OpenCV to Unity and ball tracking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opencv, simulation, game-physics

I am working on a project where I have a venue with cricket nets inside. This venue currently has a bowling machine connected to a computer and sensors to detect where the ball hits. My goal is to enhance the simulation by integrating a camera (although it's not high resolution) to record gameplay and display it to the customer after they've made their shot. I want to utilize this camera to track the ball's movement, identify two points in two different time frames, and use this data to calculate the ball's velocity and position. I then aim to transfer this information to Unity or another physics engine to create a more immersive virtual playground.

However, I have experience with Unity but not with OpenCV, which I've tried to use for ball tracking. I also need to determine when to capture the ball's position, specifically after the player hits the ball. Are there any machine learning algorithms I should consider for this task?

One challenge I've encountered is that the ball's color changes due to slightly different lighting conditions, causing tracking issues. Additionally, there are multiple balls on the ground, as we only collect them after a few overs.

Comment: Here is link https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ball+tracking+opencv&atb=v386-1&ia=web  and https://towardsdatascience.com/ball-tracking-in-volleyball-with-opencv-and-tensorflow-3d6e857bd2e7